# accessing a MBean which is boolean in wlst

Tags: python, weblogic, mbeans, wlst

Need to access a boolean value under Store and Forward Agent ...

already inside the SAF_Agent and once i do a ls(), i see a list of operations and attributes. I can perform the operations, but i am unable to get one of the attributes

the attribute is PausedForForwarding which is a boolean true or false which currently shows true which mean the SAF Agent is currently paused for forwarding

trying to check the status for above using

cmo.getPausedForForwarding()

and other options as well, but no luck, depending on the status, i want to pause or resume the SAF_Agent !!!

Help needed !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try `cmo.isPausedForForwarding()`.That works for me.

Comment: can confirm this to work! IMHO this should be marked as the correct anwser

Answer (score 0):

Ameya,

It should work if are you trying to fetch it using variable assignment like below

```
wls:/dom1/serverConfig/Servers/server1>boolValue=cmo.getVerboseEJBDeploymentEnabled()
wls:/dom1/serverConfig/Servers/server1>boolValue
'false'
```

Please check this method if you have not done

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the only get method like this : 
    var=get('PausedForForwarding'); print var